# Whats the idiomatic C# version of the Haskell version of the Maybe implementation of Alternative

Tags: c#, oop

In Haskell if I have a bunch of computations that I want to try until one of them succeeds I could do something like:

```
f :: a -> Maybe b
g :: a -> Maybe b
h :: a -> Maybe b
TryUntilSuccess :: a -> Maybe b
TryUntilSuccess x = f x <|> g x <|> h x
```

which will return the first of f, g, or h to return anything that isn't Nothing, and return Nothing if none of them succeed.

Would the C#/OOP alternative be to use the null type in an if-else chain?  I've read that in general having functions return null was a bad practice so I don't know if that would be a good alternative.

**EDIT**

heres an attempt to do something like that
okay so maybe something like

```
    MyObj func1() { /* body */ }
    MyObj func2() { /* body */ }
    MyObj func3() { /* body */ }

    if ("func1 succeeds") {return func1()}
    else if ("func2 succeeds") {return func2()}
    else if ("func3 succeeds") {return func3()}
    else {"they all failed"}
```

Comment: If you show your attempt at implementing similar behavior in c# it would help those of us who know c# and not Haskell to answer your question better.

Comment: I added an example to the question, basically if I have a bunch of methods that might fail and I just want to try them in order, what's the best way to do it?

Comment: What constitutes success versus failure. How do you intend to report failure. If failure is reported by simply returning `null`, this is really easy (and I'll update my answer accordingly).

Comment: I don't really know what is the best way to report failure, some ways I thought of were throwing an Exception or returning null. maybe there is a better way to do it.

Comment: I would recommend returning `null` as your means of reporting failure. Normally exceptions are for "exceptional" failures, but given the way you've written the code here, I suspect this isn't actually an "exceptional" failure in that it's not something that would be logged or reported to the user, and, as such, should not throw an exception, which is an expensive operation. Normally exceptional failures don't have multiple fall-back logic to handle other attempts.

Answer (score 1):

This will run `func1` and return its result if it is non-`null`. If it is `null`, it will run `func2` and return its result if it is non-`null`. If it is `null` too, it will run `func3` and return its result whether it is `null` or not.

```
return func1() ?? func2() ?? func3();
```

`??` is called the [null-coalescing operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operator), at least in c#.